# Option to Prevent back button In Chrome when using Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, back-button, browser-history

I'm struggling in my recent project in Laravel 5 project. My project was like an exam site and I need to prevent the back button to redirect back to the previous page. 
I am wondering if someone have any ideas/option/recommendation/good practice when it comes in resolving problems with the back button issue in chrome browser. I guess it is because of the cache but I don't know what exactly was the best solution for that kind of matter. 
Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can prevent back button of browser but what you can do is check some kind of flag or session value on each request in middelware and process request accordingly.

If you can specify what exactly is your purpose then i can suggest proper solution.

Comment: What do you mean in checking the flags, can you give me some link or blog to demostrate it?